# Alternatives to Windows-builtin checkdisk utility for NTFS?

Tags: ntfs, check-disk

For some reason Windows 7's checkdisk freezes and doesn't move its progress bar forward for over an hour, while the disk is still supposedly active.

Now it's possible that if I left it overnight it would finally figure out how to progress, but are there any other programs with similar functionality I could use instead?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I have serious problems with a hard drive I use SpinRite:

http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm

It cost $89 but has saved me more times than I can count.

Another alternative is to boot to your Windows 7 installation CD and run chkdsk from there.

Answer (score 0):

Run chkdsk from the repair console. Nothing then can interfere. :)