# Is windows chdsk enough or there are better alternatives to recover filesystem?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-8.1, filesystems, check-disk

Recently I have various problems of file corruption on Windows 8.1 x64 when I copy large files.
Using HD Tune Utility apparently there is no hardware problem the already present files are fine too, the memory of my PC has no error. And I raelly cannot find the cause of the issue.

The windows scandisk (launched from GUI with the default options) haven't found any problem, now since the option to perform an accurate scandisk I want to try to launch chdisk from command prompt using these flags

```
/f /r /b /x
```

With these flags the scandisk should require much more time to do extra checks, so before the start the procedure I want to know if there are better alternatives (also commercial) to Windows scandisk.

Searching on Google I have see that an user with issues similar to the mine has discovered was caused by MTF corruption... in this case is possible to recreate MTF table without lose the data?

Any other suggestion to fix the problem is welcome.

Comment: If the data on its own partition (e.g. on D:\)?   If it is just copy it somewhere else and reformate the partition. If it is the same partition as the OS this obviously will nto work.

Comment: chkdsk does not recover a filesystem, it will detect corruption within the file system and attempt to repair the damage, which basically means removing the corruption and thus files that are corrupt will become orphaned.  You should backup any important data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a free Windows utility for MFT recovery of the NTFS partition?](http://superuser.com/questions/105161/is-there-a-free-windows-utility-for-mft-recovery-of-the-ntfs-partition).  The possible duplicate isn't a perfect match, but it actually is what the author is asking about, and the answers provide a few alternatives to chkdsk which isn't required.

Comment: There is also [this](http://superuser.com/questions/123397/alternatives-to-windows-builtin-checkdisk-utility-for-ntfs?rq=1) question but the answers are not that good, the tool suggested, does something else entirely and cannot really be compared to chkdsk.

Comment: If chdisk don't find any issue mean that Filesystem is Ok or still I cannot exclude MTF table can contain some unsung corruption?

Comment: @NicoLorio: /B implies /R, and /R implies /F, so there's no point using all three when only the first will suffice.

Answer (score -1):

How are you copying these "large files"? Copy & Paste? I have found that using Windows 7 and above to copy large files, greater than 500gb, you will end up with roughly 1 in 5 corrupted copies. I was never able to track down why the data is corrupted or a way to fix the corrupted file.

I found that using [RichCopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog) or [Unstoppable Copier](http://www.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=29) is far more robust and results in less corruption.

I would shift your focus from error scanning, and more toward the copy process. One thing to do before and after copying is to compute the checksum of the file and compare them. If they are different, the file is corrupt. This process however, can take a significant amount of time on very large files, but should be considered in "mission" critical applications.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Maybe so, however, I am unable to comment as I just joined (no rep) and wanted to share my experience with corrupted large files. I used to copy 3-5 binary files a day that ranged between 750GB to 1.5TB. Until I started using other copy routines, these files would often be corrupt for no apparent reason.

Comment: You have other problems with your system then. I routinely copy large files across drives and have never had a 1% error rate, forget 20%. If Windows' copy function was so atrocious there would be lots of complaints and this issue would be very well known.